# Chrome Crash on multiple instances of chrome Driver

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

I am developing an app that opens several chrome driver instances, I am doing this by making my app multiThreaded. I mean by this, I create multiple threads and each thread open multiple chrome drivers and gather information from a specific URL. 
When the number of chrome browser is pretty big (ex. 25 ~ 30 browsers), I got the error that chrome extension crashed. I don't know if it is because of chrome browser CPU usage or if it is related to chrome.
If I started my chrome browsers headless will this solve my problem? (minimizing the CPU usage !)
In need of advice, please.

Comment: Code trials and error trace logs?

Answer (score 1):

Opening more than 10 instances of Chrome browser on a single machine while trying to performing multi-threaded automated test execution is not advisable.

Depending on the `RAM size` and `DISK usage` try increasing or decreasing the load(the number of browsers) to find the root cause.

Headless Browser is going to help as there won't be any physical memory usage with respect to method calls for test executions, exceptions might arise due to multithreading.

Comment: what does this mean? "there won't be any physical memory usage with respect to method calls for test executions".

Comment: During headless browser testing which is basically the non-GUI mode of testing, won't open chrome browser. In turn, reduce RAM usage.

Comment: sure it "opens" chrome browser.. the browser is launched, just with no visible ui.

Comment: What I was trying to point out is - 'Headless browsers are your friend if performance is critical. They are faster than real browsers since they do not come with all the overhead of starting up a browser GUI, and this equates to quicker results for your tests', head over to [link](https://saucelabs.com/blog/headless-browser-testing-101) for more details.

Comment: a headless browser still has all of the overhead.  it executes requests, parses the dom, fetches subresources, renders css, executes javascript, etc etc.  The performance differences are really negligible.